# QWebException: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'with_context'" while evaluating "doc.with_context({'lang':doc.partner_id.lang})"

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, qweb, odoo-view

I am new to odoo, I created a module by inheriting sales_order to create a custom report. I am getting the above error when I am printing the report. Need help please?

Here is the code snippets:

test/my_module.py:

```
class sale_order(models.Model):
   _name = 'sale.order'
   _description = 'Inheritance'
  _inherit = 'sale.order'
```

test/views/report_template_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
        <data>
            <template id="test_report">
                <t t-call="report.html_container"> 
                <t t-call="report.internal_layout"> 
                <t t-set="doc" t-value="doc.with_context({'lang':doc.partner_id.lang})"/> 
                <div class="page"> 
                    <div class="oe_structure"/> 
                        <div> <strong><left>User</left></strong> 
                            <p t-field="doc.user_id"/> 
                        </div> 
                     </div> 
            </t> 
           </t>
   </template>
</data>
```

How can I access records in `custom_report_template`?

Comment: I'm also wondering. Did your ever find out?

Answer (score 2):

i know i'm late but the name of the variable containing the recordSet passed to the template is docs not doc.
and you are trying to get value from a variable that don't have anything.

```
doc.with_context({'lang':doc.partner_id.lang})
```

i think you need to do `docs` not `doc` because `doc` is `None` 
This why all template in loop docs :

```
   <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
```